# Limit WFS GetCapabilities document

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getcapabilities

Does anyone know if you can limit what's shown in the GetCapabilities  document for a GeoServer WFS service?

I have restricted the workspace to read only mode (..r=* and *.*.w=NO_ONE). I hoped that would lead to that, for example CreateStoredQuery wouldn't show up in the GetCapabilities document, but it doesn't. I also only want to support GET requests, no POST requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you switch your WFS from `Complete` to `Basic` on the WFS settings page then no transactional requests will be supported but the end points will still appear in the capabilities document.

Changing permissions will not affect the output of the GetCapabilities request.

I don't think there is any way in GeoServer to limit requests to just GET (there is no reason to do this that I can think of), but you might be able to do it in tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there is no way in Geoserver to make the endpoints not appear in the capabilities document?

Comment: I don't think so, but why are you concerned?

Comment: When Inspire validates the WFS-service (with OGC TEAM Engine) it tests all the available operations in the getcapabilities document. All CreateStoredQueries and DropStoredQueries tests fails because we doesn't allow them if your not authenticated and authorized.

Comment: So don't do that! Alternatively raise a bug/enhancement report against the TEAM engine

Comment: But isn't it correct as TEAM Engine does? If the endpoints exists in the getcapabilities document, shouldn't they be supported?

Comment: No, you can return an error message for service end points that are not supported (I think) - see what happens if you turn WFS off and then ask for the capabilities for example/

Comment: You can create a custom GetCapabilities response and give the URL of that document as your endpoint