# GeoServer GetFeatureById Stored query not working

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I can't get the stored query GetFeatureById to work. The GetFeature request with id works:

> https://opendata-view.smhi.se/svar2012_coast-sea/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeNames=svar2012_coast-sea:smhi_kustvatten_och_havsomraden_SVAR_2012_2&featureID=smhi_kustvatten_och_havsomraden_SVAR_2012_2.1&version=2.0.0&

But with the stored query it doesn't:

> https://opendata-view.smhi.se/svar2012_coast-sea/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&storedquery_id=urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFeatureById&id=smhi_kustvatten_och_havsomraden_SVAR_2012_2.1&typenames=svar2012_coast-sea:smhi_kustvatten_och_havsomraden_SVAR_2012_2&version=2.0.0&

Error message:

```
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NotFound" locator="GetFeature">
  <ows:ExceptionText>Could not find feature with specified id</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As per https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342193/limit-wfs-getcapabilities-document did you you switch your WFS from Complete to Basic on the WFS settings?

Comment: @nmtoken yes it's set to Basic.

Comment: Type name and ID look correct and service reports that it supports the stored query, so unless you have a data error (which doesn't seem likely considering everything else is working), the likely issue is the server not supporting the request.

Comment: If you set it to complete do the queries work?

Comment: I don't think so. But I have to check on Monday.

Comment: No it does not work.